# RestKit mapKeyPath to Array index

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, restkit

I would like to map a given array index into a property with RestKit (OM2). I have this JSON:

```
{
  "id": "foo",
  "position": [52.63, 11.37]
}
```

which I would like to map to this Object:

```
@interface NOSearchResult : NSObject
@property(retain) NSString* place_id;
@property(retain) NSNumber* latitude;
@property(retain) NSNumber* longitude;
@end
```

I can't figure out how to map values out of the position array in my JSON into properties of my objective-c class. The mapping looks like this so far:

```
RKObjectMapping* resultMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NOSearchResult class]];
[resultMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"place_id"];
```

Now how can I add a mapping for the latitude/longitude? I tried various things, that don't work. e.g.:

```
[resultMapping mapKeyPath:@"position[0]" toAttribute:@"latitude"];
[resultMapping mapKeyPath:@"position.1" toAttribute:@"longitude"];
```

Is there a way to map `position[0]` out of the JSON into `latitude` in my object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no - [key-value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE) doesn't allow for that. For collection, only aggregate operations such as max, min, avg, sum are supported.

Your best bet is probably to add an NSArray property to NOSearchResult:

```
// NOSearchResult definition
@interface NOSearchResult : NSObject
@property(retain) NSString* place_id;
@property(retain) NSString* latitude;
@property(retain) NSNumber* longitude;
@property(retain) NSArray* coordinates;
@end

@implementation NOSearchResult
@synthesize place_id, latitude, longitude, coordinates;
@end
```

and define mapping like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* resultMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NOSearchResult class]];
[resultMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"place_id"];
[resultMapping mapKeyPath:@"position" toAttribute:@"coordinates"];
```

After that, you could manually assign latitude and longitude from coordinates.

EDIT: A good place to do latitude/longitude assignment is probably in object loader delegates

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObject:(id)object;
```

and

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader*)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray*)objects;
```

Comment: Thanks - I was already afraid it wouldn't work. The 'didLoadObject' hint was really helpful!

Comment: a better place would be in custom getters and setters for lat and lon that manipulate the underlying array data structure.